# Rails 3.1 Remote Link writing to the DB 5 times.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, database

I Have a remote link that when clicked sends an ajax request to a controller action in the background. This request creates a new database entry. The problem is that it currently writes to the database 5 times for each click.

Here is my link and controller action:

```
<a href="/link/Link Name To Be Saved" data-remote="true">click</a>

  def track_link
    y = cookies[:user_email]
    x = User.where(email: y).first
    z = x.id
    name = params[:link_name]

    w = Link.new
    w.name = name
    w.user_id = z
    w.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render action: "index" }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Well, you should trace what's going on. Maybe your action gets called 5 times. What's in your `development.log`?

Comment: I'm seeing that it calls the get request 5 times, which makes sense about the database. but why? does it have to do with the ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `jquery_ujs` file is probably being included 5 times.

Comment: Hey, I checked out the inspector while making the request and under the "initiator" column it lists 5 different .js files. they are: jquery.js application.js vendor.js active_admin.js and application.js again..How do i deal with the overlapping, especially with the active admin stuff.